# How to modify a Postgres database while debugging a Flutter app on VS Code with a virtual machine emulator?

Tags: database, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

Can not seem to understand how I can access a Postgres database that I am debugging with, how to modify it and work with it remotely.

I know Android Studio allows me to see the database that I am working with, however I am not fond of that IDE and would like to continue working in VS Code with a VM as opposed to debugging on my phone.

So far I've only found questionable solutions that do not seem to work for anyone (downloading SQLTools extension or other extensions to work with DBs).